# AMPL: tolerance for binary constraint seems to depend on other terms in model, how can I tell when this is going to happen?

Tags: precision, ampl, constraint-satisfaction

I am using AMPL to optimise a sequence of values, and I want to specify a rule that the sequence can't have more than two negative values in a row. I've implemented this by declaring a binary to flag when the sequence is negative:

```
var InventoriesDecrease{Years} binary;
param BigNumber := 1111112;
subject to EnforceInventoriesDecreaseFlag{y in Years}: 
    BalancedUse[y,"Change in Inventories"] >= (0 - BigNumber*InventoriesDecrease[y]);
```

Intent is that for a given year, change in inventories must be >= 0 if InventoriesDecrease flag is zero, and must be >= (large negative number) if InventoriesDecrease flag is one.

I then enforce the "no more than 2 consecutive negatives" rule with another constraint:

```
param MaxConsecutiveDecreasesInInventory := 2;
param NumYearsInSeries := card(Years);
subject to EnforceMaxConsecutiveDecreases 
    {y in Years: ord(y,Years) <= NumYearsInSeries-MaxConsecutiveDecreasesInInventory}:
        sum{y2 in Years: ord(y,Years)<=ord(y2,Years)<=ord(y,Years)+MaxConsecutiveDecreasesInInventory}
        (InventoriesDecrease[y2])
        <=
        MaxConsecutiveDecreasesInInventory;
```

When I set BigNumber to 1111111 I get the expected results - the output has no more than two consecutive negatives in Changes in Inventories. (This isn't actually a *good* solution for the economic problem I'm working on, but never mind that.) Checking the values for InventoriesDecrease gives me a sequence like 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 ...

But when I set BigNumber to 1111112 it gives negatives for changes in inventories every year. Looking at InventoriesDecrease, the values are either 1s or very small non-integer positives, around 1E-5 or so. This then allows changes in inventories to be negative every year (since the lower bound is now BigNumber * 1E-5 ~ 100 rather than BigNumber * 0 = 0).

If I set BigNumber to 1111111 this doesn't happen; it looks as if the binary constraint is then enforced exactly (or at least to a smaller tolerance than ~ 1E-5) so the "no more than 2 consecutive negatives" rule works as intended. Presumably something about the magnitude of BigNumber affects the tolerances that are set on InventoriesDecrease. (Solver = Gurobi, but I encountered similar problems with CPLEX.)

I expect to be working with some quite large numbers, so I'd like to have a better understanding about what triggers this behaviour. I found http://www.ampl.com/NEW/tolerate.html but there are several "to come"s and it was last updated in 1996 so I'm not holding my breath :-)

(I'm also a little surprised that decimal-1111111 is a threshold for behaviour of this sort; I would've expected something around a power of two!)